# Adyen Drop-in Data to card.encrypted.json

Tags: node.js, adyen

We are integrating payments in our application using Adyen Web **Drop-in** plugin, as we are not PCI compliant we are receiving encrypted info from Drop-in Like below :

```
{
  "data": {
      "paymentMethod": {
          "type": "scheme",
          "encryptedCardNumber" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$...",
          "encryptedExpiryMonth" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..."
          "encryptedExpiryYear" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..."
          "encryptedSecurityCode" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..."
        }
  },
  "isValid": true
}
```

We need to call  **/authorize** API and it needs encrypted data in a single property **card.encrypted.json** like follow :

```
{
   "reference":"YourPaymentReference",
   "merchantAccount":"TestMerchant",
   "amount":{
      "currency":"EUR",
      "value":1500
   },
   "additionalData":{
      "authorisationType":"PreAuth",
      "card.encrypted.json : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..*"
   }
}
```

So far we have tried to pass whole JSON provided by Drop-in in the field, but it doesn't work and we get the following response from Adyen.

```
{
    "status": 422,
    "errorCode": "174",
    "message": "Unable to decrypt data",
    "errorType": "validation"
}
```

So does anyone know how to convert our data into that **card.encrypted.json**, I've seen that there are other Adyen plugins that generate this token using custom forms, but we need to use **Drop-in** Plugin and its not generating this field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the drop-in and other components, you need to use the [`/payments`](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/#/PaymentSetupAndVerificationService/v50/payments) API.

Your /authorise examples requires minimal changes to become a /payments request. You need to pass along the `paymentMethod` object directly to the /payments request:

```
{
   "reference":"YourPaymentReference",
   "merchantAccount":"TestMerchant",
   "amount":{
      "currency":"EUR",
      "value":1500
   },
   "paymentMethod": {
       "type": "scheme",
       "encryptedCardNumber" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$...",
       "encryptedExpiryMonth" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..."
       "encryptedExpiryYear" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..."
       "encryptedSecurityCode" : "adyenjs_0_1_25$..."
   },
   "additionalData":{
      "authorisationType":"PreAuth",
   }
}
```